# Group data and add new column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

Hello people from stackeoverflow,
I have the following table:

**Input**

[image: order table]
!

I need to group by *name*, *lastname* and if one or more *status* of a person are 'sending' then the *new_col* will be 'not finished', if all  *status* of a person are 'sended' then *new_col* will be 'finished'.

**Expected output**

| name | lastname | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | Perez | not finished |
| Maria | Lopez | not finished |
| Mario | Lopez | finished |

I try grouping but I'm stuck figuring this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name, 
       lastname, 
       CASE WHEN SUM(status != 'sended')
            THEN 'not finished'
            ELSE 'finished'
            END new_col
FROM table
GROUP BY name, 
         lastname
```